# Project Rider Local Database File

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, rider

I am looking for a way to include a standart .MDF database to my C# project in Project Rider. I really like the way it works with Databases.

I know that Visual Studio uses Microsoft SQL Server databases, even for local ones, but i can't use a local file of .MDF type for an SQL Server in Porject Rider.

Is there a way to accomplish the connection? If not, what could be a good alternative for a local database?

Thanks!

Comment: why cant use you use MDF ?

Comment: I can't work with MDF files in Project Rider. There is no way to open them there. Just VS....

Comment: So it was less you cant use, more how do you use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just use a MDF file directly, it must be used with SQL Server.  If you are looking for some kind of local database just to be able to store some data and query it in SQL format, take a look at [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) or look into [Microsoft SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) or greater.

Comment: So it would be better just to switch to SQLite. Thanks for the answer!